# Extracting large multi module project from maven repository

Tags: shell, maven, nexus

I have a large multi module project with nested multi module projects. All in all, the entire project has 134 artifacts and gets built and regularly at different versions. I used to have a nexus repository manager on Windows, on which I wrote powershell scripts to be able to easily extract an entire project from nexus so that I could zip up the contents and send to those who do not have access to the nexus instance.

I have recently moved the nexus instance to a CentOS box, and so can no longer use the powershell scripts I wrote before. Before writing these scripts in shell, I was wondering if someone has already solved this problem by writing scripts, or is there a nice maven way to do this.

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: May be I misunderstand a thing here but why not offering the Nexus instance via network and let it be used during the build that's the simplest solution...

Comment: This problem arises due to network restrictions and teams working on other networks who need the maven artifacts in their nexus instance or maven repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dependency:copy-dependencies` goal

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

to copy everything necessary for your project to one directory. Then you can easily zip it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Would this also copy all artifact attachments that are not JARs, i.e. WARS, zips, EARs, etc?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I would just try it with an example project on the command line.